# What does the chaining and locking of Satan in the bottomless pit for the millennial reign accomplish?

Tags: exegesis, satan, eschatology, revelation, premillennialism

In my study of the Revelation of Jesus Christ, I am puzzled by the chaining, and the locking of Satan in the Pit for the millennial reign of Christ.

This question: *[According to premillenial view, What is the point of the Millenium reign?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9412/according-to-premillenial-view-what-is-the-point-of-the-millenium-reign)* is similar and has an answer that gives two reasons for  the millennial reign, but they do not seem to answer my question.

Here are some considerations that I have mulled over:

> 1. Satan is chained and locked in the pit, so that he can no longer tempt mankind.
> 2. Since Satan was defeated at the cross, then why is he loosed to participate in the battle of Armageddon?
> 3. Is the battle of Armageddon the final battle of the war begun in Heaven, and if so why then did God, give the one thousand year interlude in that battle?
> 4. Is the Battle at Armageddon to show Satan that even though he enlisted such a large number of mankind in his army that that was not sufficient to overcome the army of God?
> 5. Assuming that number 4 is true, then why does the judgment immediately follow Armageddon?
> 6. And finally, will Satan and all unbelievers have to bear the knowledge that their rebellion was such folly for the Eternity in the lake of fire?

Number 6 is as close as I have come to understanding this passage in the Revelation, but it still does not answer my initial question, of the purpose of the millennial reign, and why Satan is bound and locked in the bottomless pit.

From what I know of the Catholic faith they believe that the dead are put into a place known as Purgatory to await the final judgment, which gives a second chance to get into Heaven, but we protestants do not adhere to such a belief. As far as purgatory goes it would give a chance for those in purgatory to get into heaven while Satan was bound which seems a bit of a stretch to me, but as for Protestants it seems to serve no purpose for those who are already dead since their fate is sealed as far as I understand.

I can see a possible reason for Catholics but not for Protestants. Any ideas from any denomination are welcome.

Comment: One view I have heard is that the righteous will be "reviewing the records" of the wicked to see that they really do not deserve to be there. They way they are on board when they are raise unto destruction. Other than asking for a premillenial view, I don't see this question as different from [the other.](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9412/according-to-premillenial-view-what-is-the-point-of-the-millenium-reign) So if you don't put a specific theological restriction on this, it is off-topic as a Truth question. If you want a premillenial restriction, then this is a duplicate.

Comment: Anticipating this question to close, I put my answer on the other site: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9412/according-to-premillenial-view-what-is-the-point-of-the-millenium-reign/32584#32584

Comment: @fredsbend I have reworded my question to more accurately address my confusion. does that help?

Comment: Well, all you changed was the subject. There's still going to be opinions and you haven't put a specific theological frame on this.

Comment: This question may help you understand. http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/6010/does-christ-return-to-heaven-after-the-thousand-year-reign-and-then-return-to-e

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the simplest--yet most profound--reason for Satan's being chained for a thousand years is because God desires to prove to humanity once and for all that even with Satan out of the way, human beings will still reject the Lordship of Jesus Christ, thinking they are better off being masters of their own fate instead of subjects of the King of kings and Lord of lords (Revelation 17:14; 19:16).

In other words, at the end of the thousand years, no one can any longer legitimately blame only Satan for something that is deep within the heart of all of us; namely, our sin nature.

To be sure, Jesus entered time and space as the God-Man to destroy through his death and resurrection the works of the devil (1 John 3:8), but he did not enter time and space to destroy the sin nature of the creatures he created in His image. That is something each true believer needs to do of his or her volition as they put to death the works of their sinful nature (see, for example, Romans 8:13 and Colossians 3:5).

What the 10 servants of the nobleman in Jesus' parable said of their master in Luke 19 will also be on the lips of those who refuse to bow the knee to the reign and rule of Jesus on earth during the Millennium:

> "'We will not have this man to reign over us'" (vv.19 and 27).

When Satan is finally loosed from his captivity, he will have little trouble, then, in rallying troops around him in his ultimately futile attempt to depose by force the King of kings and the Lord of lords, Jesus Christ. King Jesus, in turn, will have no difficulty in defeating the prince of darkness and the father of lies, as well as all those who align themselves with him and with the beast and the false prophet. After their defeat, the unholy trinity will be cast into the lake of fire forever (see Revelation 19:20; 20:10; 20:14-15).

Only then will

> "'The kingdoms of this world . . . become the kingdoms of our Lord, and of his Christ; and he shall reign for ever and ever' (Revelation 11:15 KJV).

Comment: Your answer is great as the why in the Scriptures, but my question is the what.

Comment: @Bye: The what of what? If you mean "What is the purpose of the Millennial reign of Christ on earth?" or "What is the point of Jesus' Millennial reign?", it is to give humankind one last chance, so to speak, to align themselves with the real deal (Jesus) or the counterfeits (viz., the world, the flesh, and the devil, who will be released prior to his last-gasp effort to unseat King Jesus). Maybe I'm not reading your questions as closely as I ought. What thinkest thou? Don

Comment: No My question is not even about the millennial reign, but about the chaining and locking Satan in the bottomless pit. your answer may well tell me why he was, falls a little shot of what is accomplished by it. that is not said in a sarcastic tone, but as a comment on why it is not what I wish to learn.

Comment: @Bye: At the risk of repeating myself unnecessarily, Satan is chained so that the hearts of some men (and women) will be exposed for what they truly are, kind of like when the hearts of our first parents were exposed when they were, once they were on their own, with no devil in sight. An analogy might help. Suppose you're a drug addict in denial. You blame your "disease" on the supply side of things: the growers, the smugglers, the distributors, the dealers (and especially that kid in the ninth grade who turned you on to pot). God steps in and says, "OK, with one wave of my magic wand, I'll

Comment: remove everything and everybody involved in the supply side of things. Plus, I'll remove all alcohol from the scene and anything that could possibly be addicting. I'll even re-fashion your stomach so that you can't possibly become a glutton or a binge-er/purge-er. If you still mess up and reject my lordship in your life, then you can no longer blame me, or Satan, or anyone really, except yourself. Oh, and don't go saying I'm unfair for 'sending you to hell.' No, you did that yourself." That sort of thing. This probably didn't help, but I gave it my best shot. Don

Comment: While I appreciate your insight, If we consider that that only those still alive at the time would know that and not those resurrected just prior to judgment. Would not that be giving those still alive a second chance at salvation. and if so, will souls be saved during the millennial reign? Would God give a second chance to some but not all condemned.

Comment: That is what I was questioning by asking what it accomplished, and why I said your question gave me the why, but not the what.

Comment: @Bye: The Second Coming of Christ in the air does not signal the end of the possibility of being saved. What signals the end for each and every one of us, regardless of when we live on this earth, is physical death. People in the Millennium aren't being given a second chance. They'll live and they'll die as did all humankind prior to Christ's millennial reign on earth. If they believe in Christ, they'll be resurrected to eternal life some day, just as anyone was prior to the Millennium. During the Day of the Lord, especially during the Great Tribulation, to become (and stay) a Christian

Comment: will be difficult indeed. Consequently, there will, perhaps, be few believers and MANY unbelievers who STILL(!) refuse to repent of their sins (see Revelation 9:20-21). By the way, I believe (at least I think I do) the Day of the Lord begins when Christ takes his church home to be with him in glory and ends when God ushers in the eternal state in which "the kingdoms of this world will become the kingdoms of our Lord and of his Christ, and he shall reign forever and ever" (Revelation 11:15).

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question completely I often wondered the same thing. I have reached these two possible answers

(A) The devil is released to tempt those who were resurrected in the second ressurrection (the unbelievers). So the righteous are resurrected and rule with Christ for a thousand years then after the thousands years the second resurrection begins (resurrection of the unbelievers) the devil is loosed and this group falls to ultimate temptation and after there evil plan to invade the camp of christ is thwarted by God's power, the white throne judgement takes place and the devil and all his followers get thrown into the lake of fire and the unbelievers undertake "the second death" and then the kingdom of God (New Jerusalem) descends from heaven and the New Earth will be blessed and over abundant in natural resources and all the nations of the New Earth will be blessed from New Jerusalem (the capital of the New Universe).
Revelations 20:4-6, Revelation 20:12-13, Revelations 20:14, Revelations 11:15

(B) The second answer is a speculation. After the thousand years is over and the Devil is released he goes and accomplishes tempting angels to join his rebelion by lieing and claiming that he broke out of the pit and that he cannot be contained and some angels (whom are capable of disobedience) actually believe him and fall for his deciet and begin to go against the camp of Christ and are defeated by God's power then thrown into the lake of fire never to be released.

I believe the first answer is a more palletable and acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has mentioned the true Olive tree; the Jews. God did not assimilate the original people of His heart into the Gentile Bride.

According to Revelation symbolism, much of which typifies The Jews, the Millenial reign will be the climax of their jealousy.

Believers are given the mandate to stir them to jealousy and a desire for the Messiah they rejected but we, the grafted in ones, accepted.

Comment: What evidence do you have for this belief?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! As curiousdanii's comment suggests, your answer could really use some supportive citation, particularly to demonstrate that this represents the premillenialist view requested by the question. Please refer to our [help centre](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) for more information on what constitutes a well-supported and on-topic answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer rhetorician gave is outstanding.  I'd like to add one more point that scripture explicitly states about the millenial reign of Christ on earth: the earth will be at rest.

Now, the implications are profound, among them rhetorician's point.

Here's another implication: all of those in the *second* resurrection will experience a sharp contrast (to put it mildly ;-) of a world they knew in the first life with a world that's had a millennium to operate under Christ reigning on earth with those in the first resurrection.

"The rest of the dead did not come to life until the thousand years were completed. This is the first resurrection. Blessed and holy is the one who has a part in the first resurrection; over these the second death has no power, but they will be priests of God and of Christ and will reign with Him for a thousand years" Rev 20:5-6

Next, a 'judgement' is not, *only*, a *decision*.  Rather it is a *period of time* to come to a decision.  And, that is definitely throughout many examples in scripture where God gives mankind *time to repent*.  It is part of the judgement.

The major prophets touch some here and there on what that millenial world will be like, e.g. Isaiah chapters 65 and 66.  But, more.

Consider the implications: those who get to live a period of time under Christ's reign after having lived in this world.  Who is going to say, "Man, that prior age was great?"  *Especially* in contrast to 1,000 years of Christ on earth?  (e.g. Rev 2:27).

As for those who are fulfilled in this world, Jesus does address this, e.g. Lk 6:25 "Woe to you who are well fed now".  Indeed.  Scripture talks about how those successful by this age's standards, and feel secure or satisfied with it, are going to end up in shame.

The overwhelming majority of mankind that has experienced life in this age pretty much agree the world is a bad place.  And, that includes the overwhelming majority of the successful of this age.

It is evident in scripture many will accept Christ after experiencing the contrast.  But, rhetorician's point is a very good one: there are still going to be some who do not.

There is, explicitly, a first resurrection and a second resurrection of the rest of the dead.  Given the totality of scripture's revelation on the matter, all those in the second resurrection are not condemned.  In fact, there's another discussion on the topic God isn't even calling everyone in this age (e.g. John 6:44, "no man can come to me lest the Father draw him", and *deliberate* spiritual blindness/deafness imparted by God to many in this age).

Those in the second resurrection do not have a 'better resurrection' (Heb 11:35).

Also, consider the theme of birthright throughout the Bible and some correlations to first and second resurrection, e.g.

"Instead of your shame you will receive a double portion", Isa 61:7

It's not explicit, but there is definitely a notable correlation throughout scripture.

A last point about releasing Satan: it proves how futile mere mortal is against Satan.  Upon being released into a world without war for 1,000 years, mere mortals are still pawns in Satan's hand to stir up war against Christ.  Then, again, Christ proves how futile Satan's attempts are to thwart Him.

Apparently, Christ wants that demonstrated - again - after binding him 1,000 years.  My personal thoughts are for these reasons:

- there is no struggle between ANYTHING and God.  Period.  Satan is not a worthy opponent to God.  Yet he's fooled millinea of mankind he is just that.  (Look what exalting one's self against God did for mortals.  What do you think an even more accountable being is facing?)
- that should put mere mortal's hearts at rest, "be anxious for NOTHING" is God's will.
- God's revealed nature in scripture indicates He is righteously indignant of what Satan has done with His creation, ---and His Name---.  It's curtains for this creature in front of all mankind and the saved.

Answer (score 0):

The essence of the millennial reign is to continue and finish the teaching man was receiving back in the garden of Eden before sin interrupted. 
That teaching was meant to arm man with the knowledge of truth. It was this lack of truth that made man fall cheapishly for Satan's lies and trick.

The last days saint who are privileged to come to the knowledge of the totatilty of the truth of the word of God through the guidance of the Holy Spirit of truth would be at the forefront with Christ teaching the patriarchal saints and all those clouds of witnesses who began the race before us but were not fulfilled yet because their fulfillment depended on the last runners fulfillment (the first shall be the last and the last be the first). 
At the millennial reign, the truth of the kingdom which is a life in the last days saints will be manifested and taught for the world to see and learn for THY KINGDOM COME AND THY WILL BE DONE ON EARTH AS IT IS IN HEAVEN but as it is written, the world of sin wouldn't be able to accept the Spirit of truth even in His beauty and glory  but as many that are the children of the kingdom of God would embrace the Spirit of Truth. 
Satan would be released again after the reign and as  many who has not the Spirit of truth would still be deceived to follow him to be perpetually doomed.

This sets the stage for the final judgment and reward for every dead and living souls respectively.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. What resources or quotes do you have to support this answer? Please [edit] this to add some references that show this is what premillennial teachers teach.